# orderBy order numbers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have a JSON feed which contains array of objects. Each array has a field called **"status"** with following values - **Yes, No, Not Now, Never**
I want to assign an order number to it

So

```
Yes(1) , 
Not Now(2), 
No(3), 
Never(4)
```

Now whenever I sort the table which contains this status. 
It must be sorted by orderNo. of the status and not alphabetically.

I don't need complete answer, just a point to right direction will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a field called `orderNo` to each object and populate this value with the order you defined after you retrieved the value from API.

```
[
    {
        "status": "Yes",
        "orderNo": 1,
        ....
    },
    {
        "status": "Never",
        "orderNo": 4,
        ....
    }
]
```

You can process it in the callback of the `$http` or `$resource` service like this:

```
angular.forEach(objects, function(o){
    if(o.status === 'Yes') o.orderNo = 1;
    else if(o.status === 'Not Now') o.orderNo = 2;
    else if(o.status === 'No') o.orderNo = 3;
    else if(o.status === 'Never') o.orderNo = 4;
});
```

Comment: @KuldeepDaftary you can do it in front end.

Comment: So you mean I need to call a function once JSON data is received in scope and then update it?

Comment: Ahh I see.. I'll give it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix the backend, then all you need to do is write a sorting function for angular to use.  In your case, in your angular controller, write

```
$scope.myCustomSort = function(elem)
{
  switch(elem.status)
  {
    case "Yes": return 1;
    case "Not now": return 2;
    case "No": return 3;
    case "Never": return 4;
    default: return 10;
  }
}
```

then, in your HTML, pass it as the `orderBy` function.

```
<myThing ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:myCustomSort"></myThing>
```

As long as the `myCustomSort` method is available to the scope of whoever controls your `ng-repeat`, it will use your custom sort method.

I'll [link you to the doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy), though it's not obvious that you can do this unless you read the whole thing.  But you can see that `orderBy` takes an expression, which can be your own function (or array of functions), where you can return your own custom value that will be sorted with `<` and `>`.